# How can I be notified when a specific file on my Windows 10 computer has been updated?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

Sample use case:
A project manager updates ProjectSchedule.pdf on a network drive. The timestamp on the Date Modified metadata updates. Some app/script/service catches the updated timestamp and notifies the user that the file has been updated and now I know that I need to check for an updated schedule.

What I've tried:
Preliminary searching suggested Microsoft Flow, which requires an On-Premises Gateway, which requires a license I did not have and don't want to buy.

Ideally, this would be a simple System Tray applet.

Comment: Try File Activity Watch, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_activity_watch.html . That said, this question belongs on Software Recommendations, https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/